# Nreco pdf generator allways throwing ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm using Nreco Pdf Generator.
A few days ago i'm facing allways an odd behaviour. Allways throwing: 
**"Cannot generate PDF: Exit with code 1 due to network error: ConnectionRefusedError (exit code: 1)"**

I couldn't find similar error on my searches.

Did someone faced such kind of problem?

Comment: This is wkhtmltopdf error (PdfGenerator is a wrapper for this tool) that means that HTML template has a reference to external resource (css, js, image etc) that cannot be resolved.

Comment: this is so weird bro, I use Rotativa (ASP.net MVC) which has the same core: wkhtmltopdf. On my localhost renders everything perfect. On my main domain works without any issues. The SAME code running on a different subdomain (dev.domain.com) Doesn't work. I have no clue why.